# C++ GetAsyncKeyState problem

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to do simple programm which would help me while I play.
My code works fine when game is not active but when I activate my game and go fullscreen my if statements won't work.

Here is example:

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
{
    SetCursorPos(620, 321);
}
```

The code is in while(true) loop.

How do I use these keys while I'm playing?

Answer (score 0):

By activating full screen Im assuming you are writing a DirectX based game. In which case your problem probably lies with the SetCursorPos call rather than GetAsyncKeyState.

DirectX famously has issues with cursors.  This is caused by shoddy drivers.

You may want to call

```
ShowCursort( NULL );
pDevice->ShowCursor( TRUE );
```

If this isn't your problem then, quite frankly, I need more information like what exactly you are trying to do ...

Comment: That isn't the problem because if I try to cout something with that same condition it won't work. Only work when game is not active.

Comment: @Henri:  So what happens if you cout the return value of GetAsyncKeyState?  What values is it returning?

Comment: It returns 0 when nothing is pressed. -32767 is returned when key is pressed. It also returns 1 which corresponds KEY_UP, I suppose. It won't return nothing but 0 when game is activated. I guess return values aren't the problem.